# How to get auto complete search location results as GMSPlaces instead of GMSAutocompletePrediction with Google place API in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api, google-local-search

Actually, I get the corresponding response as in the form of [GMSAutoCompletepredictions](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_prediction) for my auto completion location search request with Google API. With the prediction results, we didn't get more detail info like coordinates, formatted detail address, etc of location.

If we need more detail info for location, we need to to give one more request to Google plcaes API with place ID value avail in prediction results. This method may increase the API usage and affect the app performance.

Please help me to overcome this problem. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way for now. To get more info from prediction results you have to request the place by placeId.